# Resource missing errors on Jenkins build of Android project with Couchbase Lite

Tags: android, maven, jenkins, gradle, couchbase-lite

I have an Android project that integrates Couchbase and it builds nicely on my Windows computer. But I want to have a continuous integration for this project, so I am trying so setup a Jenkins build. The problem is that gradle fails to find resources related to the maven repository of Couchbase.

The command I use to build my project is `gradlew assembleRelease --info`. The build is successful every time I do it on my computer, but on my Jenkins server, it fails with this log :

```
[Gradle] - Launching build.
[RetailingAppAndroidProd] $ /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RetailingAppAndroidProd/gradlew assembleRelease --info
Downloading http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-all.zip
...................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Unzipping /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RetailingAppAndroidProd/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.8-all/2kopnp0i5dq014k75fp36m3vd5/gradle-1.8-all.zip to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RetailingAppAndroidProd/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.8-all/2kopnp0i5dq014k75fp36m3vd5
Set executable permissions for: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RetailingAppAndroidProd/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.8-all/2kopnp0i5dq014k75fp36m3vd5/gradle-1.8/bin/gradle
Starting Build
Settings evaluated using empty settings script.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RetailingAppAndroidProd/build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'RetailingAppAndroidProd']
Evaluating root project 'RetailingAppAndroidProd' using build file '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RetailingAppAndroidProd/build.gradle'.
Starting file lock listener thread.
Compiling build file '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RetailingAppAndroidProd/build.gradle' using BuildScriptClasspathScriptTransformer.
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/0.6.3/gradle-0.6.3.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/sdk-common/22.2.1/sdk-common-22.2.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/0.6.3/builder-0.6.3.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint/22.2.1/lint-22.2.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/proguard/proguard-gradle/4.9/proguard-gradle-4.9.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/proguard/proguard-parent/4.9/proguard-parent-4.9.pom
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/proguard/proguard-parent/4.9/proguard-parent-4.9.jar]
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/sdklib/22.2.1/sdklib-22.2.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/common/22.2.1/common-22.2.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/0.6.3/builder-model-0.6.3.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/0.6.3/builder-test-api-0.6.3.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/22.2.1/manifest-merger-22.2.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.48/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.48.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/22.2.1/ddmlib-22.2.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/22.2.1/lint-checks-22.2.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/proguard/proguard-base/4.9/proguard-base-4.9.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/22.2.1/layoutlib-api-22.2.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/dvlib/22.2.1/dvlib-22.2.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.1.1/httpclient-4.1.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-client/4.1.1/httpcomponents-client-4.1.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/project/4.1.1/project-4.1.1.pom
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/project/4.1.1/project-4.1.1.jar]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-client/4.1.1/httpcomponents-client-4.1.1.jar]
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.1/httpmime-4.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-client/4.1/httpcomponents-client-4.1.pom
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-client/4.1/httpcomponents-client-4.1.jar]
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.0/commons-compress-1.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/11/commons-parent-11.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.pom
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.jar]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/11/commons-parent-11.jar]
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/13.0.1/guava-13.0.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava-parent/13.0.1/guava-parent-13.0.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/7/oss-parent-7.pom
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/7/oss-parent-7.jar]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava-parent/13.0.1/guava-parent-13.0.1.jar]
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/kxml2/kxml2/2.3.0/kxml2-2.3.0.pom
kxml2#kxml2;2.3.0 is relocated to net.sf.kxml#kxml2;2.3.0. Please update your dependencies.
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.48/bcprov-jdk15on-1.48.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/kxml/kxml2/2.3.0/kxml2-2.3.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-api/22.2.1/lint-api-22.2.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/4.0/asm-analysis-4.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-parent/4.0/asm-parent-4.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/ow2/1.3/ow2-1.3.pom
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/ow2/1.3/ow2-1.3.jar]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-parent/4.0/asm-parent-4.0.jar]
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.1/httpcore-4.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-core/4.1/httpcomponents-core-4.1.pom
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-core/4.1/httpcomponents-core-4.1.jar]
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/5/commons-parent-5.pom
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/5/commons-parent-5.jar]
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.4/commons-codec-1.4.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/4.0/asm-4.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/external/lombok/lombok-ast/0.2.1/lombok-ast-0.2.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/4.0/asm-tree-4.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/0.6.3/gradle-0.6.3.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/sdk-common/22.2.1/sdk-common-22.2.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/0.6.3/builder-0.6.3.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint/22.2.1/lint-22.2.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/proguard/proguard-gradle/4.9/proguard-gradle-4.9.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/sdklib/22.2.1/sdklib-22.2.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/common/22.2.1/common-22.2.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/0.6.3/builder-model-0.6.3.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/0.6.3/builder-test-api-0.6.3.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/22.2.1/manifest-merger-22.2.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.48/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.48.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/22.2.1/ddmlib-22.2.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/22.2.1/lint-checks-22.2.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/proguard/proguard-base/4.9/proguard-base-4.9.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/22.2.1/layoutlib-api-22.2.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/dvlib/22.2.1/dvlib-22.2.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.1.1/httpclient-4.1.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.1/httpmime-4.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.0/commons-compress-1.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/13.0.1/guava-13.0.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.48/bcprov-jdk15on-1.48.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/kxml/kxml2/2.3.0/kxml2-2.3.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-api/22.2.1/lint-api-22.2.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/4.0/asm-analysis-4.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.1/httpcore-4.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.4/commons-codec-1.4.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/4.0/asm-4.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/external/lombok/lombok-ast/0.2.1/lombok-ast-0.2.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/4.0/asm-tree-4.0.jar
Compiling build file '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/RetailingAppAndroidProd/build.gradle' using BuildScriptTransformer.
Creating properties on demand (a.k.a. dynamic properties) has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please read http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html for information on the replacement for dynamic properties.
Deprecated dynamic property: "home" on "root project 'RetailingAppAndroidProd'", value: "/opt/android-sdk-linux/".
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/]
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/couchbase/cblite/CBLite/1.0.0-beta/CBLite-1.0.0-beta.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/couchbase/cblite/CBLite/1.0.0-beta/CBLite-1.0.0-beta.jar]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/com/couchbase/cblite/CBLite/1.0.0-beta/CBLite-1.0.0-beta.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/com/couchbase/cblite/CBLite/1.0.0-beta/CBLite-1.0.0-beta.jar]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/couchbase/cblite/CBLiteJavascript/1.0.0-beta/CBLiteJavascript-1.0.0-beta.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/couchbase/cblite/CBLiteJavascript/1.0.0-beta/CBLiteJavascript-1.0.0-beta.jar]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/com/couchbase/cblite/CBLiteJavascript/1.0.0-beta/CBLiteJavascript-1.0.0-beta.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/com/couchbase/cblite/CBLiteJavascript/1.0.0-beta/CBLiteJavascript-1.0.0-beta.jar]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/couchbase/cblite/CBLiteEktorp/1.0.0-beta/CBLiteEktorp-1.0.0-beta.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/couchbase/cblite/CBLiteEktorp/1.0.0-beta/CBLiteEktorp-1.0.0-beta.jar]
Download http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/com/couchbase/cblite/CBLiteEktorp/1.0.0-beta/CBLiteEktorp-1.0.0-beta.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-jdk14/1.6.1/slf4j-jdk14-1.6.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-parent/1.6.1/slf4j-parent-1.6.1.pom
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-parent/1.6.1/slf4j-parent-1.6.1.jar]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ektorp/org.ektorp/1.2.3/org.ektorp-1.2.3.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ektorp/org.ektorp/1.2.3/org.ektorp-1.2.3.jar]
Download http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/org/ektorp/org.ektorp/1.2.3/org.ektorp-1.2.3.pom
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ektorp/org.ektorp.parent/1.2.3/org.ektorp.parent-1.2.3.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ektorp/org.ektorp.parent/1.2.3/org.ektorp.parent-1.2.3.jar]
Download http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/org/ektorp/org.ektorp.parent/1.2.3/org.ektorp.parent-1.2.3.pom
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/org/ektorp/org.ektorp.parent/1.2.3/org.ektorp.parent-1.2.3.jar]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/maven-metadata.xml]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ektorp/org.ektorp.android/1.2.3/org.ektorp.android-1.2.3.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/ektorp/org.ektorp.android/1.2.3/org.ektorp.android-1.2.3.jar]
Download http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/org/ektorp/org.ektorp.android/1.2.3/org.ektorp.android-1.2.3.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.1/slf4j-api-1.6.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.8.6/jackson-core-asl-1.8.6.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.8.6/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.6.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient-cache/4.1.1/httpclient-cache-4.1.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.0.1/commons-io-2.0.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/15/commons-parent-15.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/7/apache-7.pom
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/7/apache-7.jar]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/15/commons-parent-15.jar]

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'RetailingAppAndroidProd'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_DebugCompile'.
      > Could not find com.couchbase.cblite:CBLite:1.0.0-beta.
        Required by:
            :RetailingAppAndroidProd:unspecified
            :RetailingAppAndroidProd:unspecified > com.couchbase.cblite:CBLiteEktorp:1.0.0-beta
      > Could not find com.couchbase.cblite:CBLiteJavascript:1.0.0-beta.
        Required by:
            :RetailingAppAndroidProd:unspecified

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 20.194 secs
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

As you can see, there is a bunch of `Resource missing.` errors and that's why my build is failing. I've searched a lot on the web to find what I must add to my Jenkins environment for it to build successfully my project but I can't find any solution. Here is my build.gradle file for reference :

```
home = System.getenv("ANDROID_HOME")

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url "http://files.couchbase.com/maven2/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.couchbase.cblite:CBLite:1.0.0-beta'
    compile 'com.couchbase.cblite:CBLiteJavascript:1.0.0-beta'
    compile 'com.couchbase.cblite:CBLiteEktorp:1.0.0-beta'

    instrumentTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:4.3'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')

        signingConfigs {
            release {
                ...
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType(Compile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

Does someone know how to solve those `Resource missing.` errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the `com.couchbase.cblite` package is not supported the same way it was several months ago, so the build fails when gradle tries to fetch the projects of this package from couchbase maven. I managed to get further in the build process by adding the jars that were cached on my computer from the time where gradle was able to fetch them from couchbase maven.